# How to remove white frame or borders into the canvas map Mapbox

Tags: css, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a project with Angular 10, and I have been work with Mapbox to show a path routes. As is normal in Angular splits the different parts of the application in components, so I decided to split the component that go to render the map in other, and call into the principal map component. But, I have been getting an issue about the white borders or frames on top and bottom inside any container I had put the map.

#### new-map.component.ts

```
<details>
  <summary class="bg-light text-dark">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light
                bg-light fs-3 justify-content-end"
                (click)="changeMapArrow()">
      <span class="material-icons">
        <b>{{arrowClass}}</b>
      </span>
    </nav>
  </summary>
  <app-mini-map></app-mini-map>
</details>
```

#### mini-map.component.ts

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6 ml-0">
        <b>Needs to know:</b>
        <span class="text-primary ml-3">
          <b>4
            <span class="material-icons check-icon-position mr-1">
              check_circle_outline
            </span>
          </b>
        </span>
        |
        <span class="text-danger ml-2">
          <b>2 ETA Delay</b>
        </span>

      </div>

      <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-row justify-content-end align-items-start">

        <p class="text-muted">Style map:</p>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check ml-3" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>
        <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted"
                for="option1" (click)="setMapStyle('gray', 'to_gray')">
                <b>Gray</b>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check ml-3" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted"
                for="option2" (click)="setMapStyle('dark', 'to_dark')">
                <b>Dark</b>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted"
                for="option4" (click)="setMapStyle('color', 'to_color')">
                <b>Color</b>
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map-container" class="col-12">
    <div #miniMapa class="border-rnd-map mini-mapa-test"></div>
    <ul class="list-group" [style.display]="!cardinalPointsMenu ? 'none' : 'block'" >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let point of pointsToFitBound">
        <li class="list-group-item"
            (click)="moveToFitArea(point.fitPoint)"
            *ngIf="point.ableToShow">
          {{point.cardinalPoint}}
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### styles applied over the mini-map.component.sass

```
#map-container
  width: 100%
  height: 200px
  margin: 0 auto

.mini-mapa-test
  width: 100%
  height: 500px
  margin: 0 auto
```

[image: top frame]
[image: bottom frame]

I had tried multiples HTML element container different to the div, and still happening the same error. These errors don't appear, when I use a single div into the father component, and just in that way works.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
<div id="map"></div>

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question, Do you test inside the other container?, I found out the problem, is an issue generated by the map editor of the company.

Comment: No I don't use a container.
This works too without having to set the position: absolute that may cause alignment issues:
`
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`